# deploy a project on multiple server without any library conflicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, containers, data-science

I have build a data science project on the window and want to deploy it on multiple Linux servers so i'm trying to configure project environment for one server but facing a bunch of errors and library conflicts. after spending a whole day on it now I'm thinking that if I configured one server then what about other servers?

i had also used requirements.txt file for configuring project environment but unable to succeed due to cross-platform issues.

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

is there any way to make a container/package (for cross-platform) for my project then i could deploy it on the server and run it?

> Note: i don't wanna use docker etc, need a pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a virtual environment??

```
apt install virtualenv
mkdir youproject
cd youproject
git clone ... (or whatever)
virtualenv -p python3.x (or 2.x) .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It creates an isolated python environment where no other libs apart from your requierements.txt exist.

Comment: yes i have tried after making virtualenv, i run this "pip install -r requirements.txt" but due to cross-platform I faced lot of issues

Comment: Maybe the problem is how you set your requirements in the requierements.txt file